# Problem Boltzmann distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, homework-and-exercises

I am trying to solve a problem about boltzmann distribution.

```
If(A)=0.74
Uf(V)=0.037
Ia(A)=0.130
```

I have to find `N, ln N, ln N0, N0, T(K)`
I know that `e=1.6E-19` and `k=1.38E-23`

Formulae:

```
N=Ia/e -> N=0.130/1.6E-19=8.13E+17
ln N=ln N0-(e/kT)Uf
```

How can i find out ln N if i don`n know N0 and how may i find T(K)

Comment: I think you need to give a *lot* more context - what are these quantities you refer to? What is the setup? How much material (how many atoms) do you have? As it is currently written, this question is unclear. Very.

Comment: Oh - and don't post [the same question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143579/26969) twice. It doesn't make it any more likely that a badly phrased question will get a good answer

Comment: these are all the data of problem that my teacher gave to solve

Comment: I have to believe that the quantities given were defined, and had units; and that maybe he or she even told you whether this was a gas, electrons, ...

Comment: should i make you some pictures to my note book maybe you wil have a clue how to solve this

Comment: I don't know if that will work. Maybe giving the exact question as given might help but then this risks becoming a "do my work for me" question which get closed on this site. But you definitely need to give more context.

Comment: http://imgur.com/tOAfI2P,66t3Lwc#0 this is the lession read second image directions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18239/discussion-between-filip-and-floris).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find $N$ from the expression $$N = \frac{I_a}{e}$$ which you have stated yourself (equation (4) in the problem) - no need to find $N_0$ first.

Plotting $\ln(N)$ as a function of $U_f$ will give you a straight line (according to equation (3) from the problem), with an intercept equal to $\ln(N_0)$ and a slope equal to $\frac{e}{kT}$. Since you know $e$ and $k$, it should be easy to find $T$.